# What reasonable options for model persistency for sklearn models exists?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

`joblib.dump()` seems to be the intended method for storing a trained sklearn models for later load and usage. I like the compression option and ease of use, but later loading with `joblib.load()` is slow. It takes 20 seconds to load a SVM model, trained on a reasonable small dataset (~10k texts). The model (stored with compress=3, as a recommended [compromise](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.dump.html)) takes 100MB as dumped file.

For my own use (analysis), I needn't worry about speed of loading a model, but I have one I'd like to share with colleagues, and would like to make it as easy and quick as possible for them. I find examples of alternatives to joblib, e.g. pickle, json or [hdfs](http://thiagomarzagao.com/2015/12/07/model-persistence-without-pickles/). All are basically the same idea, dump a binary object to disk.

I find [langid.py](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py), as an example that I suspect is created in a similar manner as a sklearn model. To me it looks like the whole model is encoded as some kind of string (base64?) and just pasted into the script itself. Is this a solution? How is this done?

Are there any other strategies that might be viable?

Comment: How big is your model in memory vs on disk?

Comment: @elyase 194.6MB in memory (according to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pympler) vs 101.2MB on disk (but then with the compression found in `joblib.dump()`).